# Redirection URL is not being formed correctly with window.open()

Tags: window.open

My requirement is that when I click on a dropdownlist option the page should reload with a new URL. I am using window.open() to load the new URL.

When I pass a direct URL(`www.google.com`) it works fine but when I read the URL in a variable it's getting appended with the parent window URL.

If my parent window URL is: `https://parentURL/home`, and new URL is `www.google.com` then the resulting URL is being formed as `https://parentURL/home/www.google.com`, the expected result should be `www.google.com` in the same page.

```
$(function(){
  $("#ChatDropDown").change(function(){
     var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
     window.open(selectedOption,"_self");
     alert("You have selected: " + selectedOption);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
window.location.assign( window.location.href + '#abcd')
```

if you want to open new url in same tab then you have to prepend 'https://' in new url. Ex : if your new url is www.google.co.in then variable value

```
var newurl = 'https://' + 'www.google.co.in' ;
```

then use.

```
window.location.replace(newurl);
```

**Note : if new url doesn't support https then http will also work.**

Comment: No this again does the same thing, it appends the new URL to the parent one.